# Multibyte UART messages of different lengths using UartLite

Tags: c++, embedded, uart, xilinx

I have an Arty Board using XUartLite to communicate with my laptop.

I want to receive multibyte messages of differing lengths. The second byte contains the message type and I can then determine how many more bytes remain in the buffer to retrieve.

I have done this successfully after adapting the code found [here](https://lancesimms.com/Xilinx/VivadoFiles/VC707_Microblaze_UART_to_LED/main.c) (Thank you Lance Simms).

My issue is that, if I use the  `XUartLite_RecvByte` method inside my interrupt routine to request the correct number of bytes, because it is a blocking call, if something goes wrong then I will be stuck waiting for a byte which never arrived - and then when the next message comes it will be looking for the wrong data.

Alternatively, if I use`XUartLite_Recv` method, which is non-blocking, and specify the number of bytes unless I debug and step through it doesn't retrieve the bytes, and doesn't trigger another interrupt for those bytes.

Ideally, I would like the interrupt to trigger the `RecvHandler` when the message has completed being received as each multi-byte message is being sent every 1/2 second. Messages can be 7,8,10 or 13 bytes long.

Or set the specified number of bytes to be the maximum (13) and have it timeout if it's not filled after a certain period from receiving the first byte.

In the example below I am sending the message "foobar". The interrupt calls the `RecvHandler` method after the first byte "f" and then it manually calls 5 times to get "oobar". Then it echos it back.

```
//NAME:
//  main.c
//
//PURPOSE:
//  This C file is meant to be built with the Xilinx SDK and run as an
//  ELF file on a Microblaze processor.
//
//AUTHOR:
//  Lance Simms
//  Note: Code uses Xilinx examples included with Vivado.
// https://lancesimms.com/Xilinx/VivadoFiles/VC707_Microblaze_UART_to_LED/main.c
//
//DATE:
//  01/09/17
//
/***************************** Include Files *********************************/

#include "xparameters.h"
#include <xil_printf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "xil_exception.h"
#include "xuartlite.h"
#include "xintc.h"
#include "xgpio_l.h"
#include "xenv.h"

/************************** Constant Definitions *****************************/

/*
 * The following constants map to the XPAR parameters created in the
 * xparameters.h file. They are defined here such that a user can easily
 * change all the needed parameters in one place.
 */
#define UARTLITE_DEVICE_ID      XPAR_UARTLITE_0_DEVICE_ID
#define INTC_DEVICE_ID          XPAR_INTC_0_DEVICE_ID
#define UARTLITE_INT_IRQ_ID     XPAR_INTC_0_UARTLITE_0_VEC_ID
#define GPIO_REG_BASEADDR       0x40000000

/*
 * The following constant controls the length of the buffers to be sent
 * and received with the UartLite device.
 */
#define TEST_BUFFER_SIZE        500

/************************** Function Prototypes ******************************/

int SetupUartLite(u16 DeviceId);

int SetupInterruptSystem(XUartLite *UartLitePtr);

void SendHandler(void *CallBackRef, unsigned int EventData);

void RecvHandler(void *CallBackRef, unsigned int EventData);

void resetBuffer();

void printBuffer();

/************************** Variable Definitions *****************************/

 XUartLite UartLite;             /* The instance of the UartLite Device */
 XUartLite_Config *UartLite_Cfg; /* The instance of the UartLite Config */
 XIntc InterruptController;      /* The instance of the Interrupt Controller */

 /*
  * The following buffers are used in this example to send and receive data
  * with the UartLite.
  */
 u8 SendBuffer[TEST_BUFFER_SIZE];
 u8 ReceiveBuffer[TEST_BUFFER_SIZE];

 /* Here are the pointers to the buffer */
 u8* ReceiveBufferPtr = &ReceiveBuffer[0];

 /*
  * The following counters are used to determine when the entire buffer has
  * been sent and received.
  */
 static volatile int TotalReceivedCount;
 static volatile int TotalSentCount;


int main()
{
    //Variable definitions
    int Status=0;

    //Set up the UART and configure the interrupt handler for bytes in RX buffer
    Status = SetupUartLite(UARTLITE_DEVICE_ID);

    //Get a reference pointer to the Uart Configuration
    UartLite_Cfg = XUartLite_LookupConfig(UARTLITE_DEVICE_ID);

    //Print out the info about our XUartLite instance
    xil_printf("\n\r");
    xil_printf("Serial Port Properties ------------------\n\r");
    xil_printf("Device ID : %d\n\r", UartLite_Cfg->DeviceId);
    xil_printf("Baud Rate : %d\n\r", UartLite_Cfg->BaudRate);
    xil_printf("Data Bits : %d\n\r", UartLite_Cfg->DataBits);
    xil_printf("Base Addr : %08X\n\r", UartLite_Cfg->RegBaseAddr);
    xil_printf("\n\r");


    // Run
    while (1){};

    //End of program
    return Status;
}

/****************************************************************************/
/**
*
* This function does a minimal test on the UartLite device and driver as a
* design example. The purpose of this function is to illustrate
* how to use the XUartLite component.
*
* This function sends data and expects to receive the same data through the
* UartLite. The user must provide a physical loopback such that data which is
* transmitted will be received.
*
* This function uses interrupt driver mode of the UartLite device. The calls
* to the UartLite driver in the handlers should only use the non-blocking
* calls.
*
* @param    DeviceId is the Device ID of the UartLite Device and is the
*       XPAR_<uartlite_instance>_DEVICE_ID value from xparameters.h.
*
* @return   XST_SUCCESS if successful, otherwise XST_FAILURE.
*
* @note
*
* This function contains an infinite loop such that if interrupts are not
* working it may never return.
*
****************************************************************************/
int SetupUartLite(u16 DeviceId)
{
    int Status;

    /*
     * Initialize the UartLite driver so that it's ready to use.
     */
    Status = XUartLite_Initialize(&UartLite, DeviceId);
    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    /*
     * Perform a self-test to ensure that the hardware was built correctly.
     */
    Status = XUartLite_SelfTest(&UartLite);
    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    /*
     * Connect the UartLite to the interrupt subsystem such that interrupts can
     * occur. This function is application specific.
     */
    Status = SetupInterruptSystem(&UartLite);
    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    /*
     * Setup the handlers for the UartLite that will be called from the
     * interrupt context when data has been sent and received, specify a
     * pointer to the UartLite driver instance as the callback reference so
     * that the handlers are able to access the instance data.
     */
    XUartLite_SetSendHandler(&UartLite, SendHandler, &UartLite);
    XUartLite_SetRecvHandler(&UartLite, RecvHandler, &UartLite);

    /*
     * Enable the interrupt of the UartLite so that interrupts will occur.
     */
    XUartLite_EnableInterrupt(&UartLite);
    XUartLite_Recv(&UartLite, ReceiveBufferPtr, 1);

    return XST_SUCCESS;
}

/*****************************************************************************/
/**
*
* This function is the handler which performs processing to send data to the
* UartLite. It is called from an interrupt context such that the amount of
* processing performed should be minimized. It is called when the transmit
* FIFO of the UartLite is empty and more data can be sent through the UartLite.
*
* This handler provides an example of how to handle data for the UartLite,
* but is application specific.
*
* @param    CallBackRef contains a callback reference from the driver.
*       In this case it is the instance pointer for the UartLite driver.
* @param    EventData contains the number of bytes sent or received for sent
*       and receive events.
*
* @return   None.
*
* @note     None.
*
****************************************************************************/
void SendHandler(void *CallBackRef, unsigned int EventData)
{
    TotalSentCount = EventData;
}
/****************************************************************************/
/**
*
* This function is the handler which performs processing to receive data from
* the UartLite. It is called from an interrupt context such that the amount of
* processing performed should be minimized.  It is called data is present in
* the receive FIFO of the UartLite such that the data can be retrieved from
* the UartLite. The size of the data present in the FIFO is not known when
* this function is called.
*
* This handler provides an example of how to handle data for the UartLite,
* but is application specific.
*
* @param    CallBackRef contains a callback reference from the driver, in
*       this case it is the instance pointer for the UartLite driver.
* @param    EventData contains the number of bytes sent or received for sent
*       and receive events.
*
* @return   None.
*
* @note     None.
*
****************************************************************************/
void RecvHandler(void *CallBackRef, unsigned int EventData)
{
    if(ReceiveBuffer[0] == 'f') //Look at the start of the message to determine the remaining bytes.
    {
        ReceiveBufferPtr++; // 1 Byte has been found so increment the buffer ptr.
        for(int i=1;i<6;i++){
        ReceiveBuffer[i]=XUartLite_RecvByte(0x40600000U);
        }
        ReceiveBufferPtr+=5; //Non-blocking but it should be successful. so increment by 5.
    }

    printBuffer(); // print the contents of the buffer.


    XUartLite_ResetFifos(&UartLite); // Reset the FIFOs
    resetBuffer(); // Reset the contents of the buffer.

    ReceiveBufferPtr = &ReceiveBuffer[0]; // Reset the pointer back to the start of the buffer.
    XUartLite_Recv(&UartLite, ReceiveBufferPtr, 1); // Get ready to receive another byte.
}

void resetBuffer()
{
    for(int i=0;i<TEST_BUFFER_SIZE;i++){
            ReceiveBuffer[i]=0;
        }
}
void printBuffer()
{
    //return the message
    XUartLite_Send(&UartLite,&ReceiveBuffer[0],6);
}
/****************************************************************************/
/**
*
* This function setups the interrupt system such that interrupts can occur
* for the UartLite device. This function is application specific since the
* actual system may or may not have an interrupt controller. The UartLite
* could be directly connected to a processor without an interrupt controller.
* The user should modify this function to fit the application.
*
* @param    UartLitePtr contains a pointer to the instance of the UartLite
*           component which is going to be connected to the interrupt
*           controller.
*
* @return   XST_SUCCESS if successful, otherwise XST_FAILURE.
*
* @note     None.
*
****************************************************************************/
int SetupInterruptSystem(XUartLite *UartLitePtr)
{

    int Status;

    /*
     * Initialize the interrupt controller driver so that it is ready to
     * use.
     */
    Status = XIntc_Initialize(&InterruptController, INTC_DEVICE_ID);
    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    /*
     * Connect a device driver handler that will be called when an interrupt
     * for the device occurs, the device driver handler performs the
     * specific interrupt processing for the device.
     */
    Status = XIntc_Connect(&InterruptController, UARTLITE_INT_IRQ_ID,
               (XInterruptHandler)XUartLite_InterruptHandler,
               (void *)UartLitePtr);
    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    /*
     * Start the interrupt controller such that interrupts are enabled for
     * all devices that cause interrupts, specific real mode so that
     * the UartLite can cause interrupts through the interrupt controller.
     */
    Status = XIntc_Start(&InterruptController, XIN_REAL_MODE);
    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    /*
     * Enable the interrupt for the UartLite device.
     */
    XIntc_Enable(&InterruptController, UARTLITE_INT_IRQ_ID);

    /*
     * Initialize the exception table.
     */
    Xil_ExceptionInit();

    /*
     * Register the interrupt controller handler with the exception table.
     */
    Xil_ExceptionRegisterHandler(XIL_EXCEPTION_ID_INT,
             (Xil_ExceptionHandler)XIntc_InterruptHandler,
             &InterruptController);

    /*
     * Enable exceptions.
     */
    Xil_ExceptionEnable();

    return XST_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions:

1. At the end of your handler function, check if the interrupt have been set to pending again, meaning another data has arrived while you treat the first one. In this case restart the handler code from the beginning to treat the new data. You can so loop in the handler until no more data are present.
2. The problem I think about is that your handler code is too long so you can miss some data while treating one, so the other solution is to just increment a global variable in your handler and treat any data in the `while(1){}` of the `main()` function. So a simple `data_to_treat++;` in the handler could be processed sufficiently fast to not miss any data.

By the way a `while(1){}` is not recommend in an embedded environment since it consumes lot's of power for nothing, you should put the CPU asleep and wake it up when you need your data to be treated, for example with the interrupt.